# jQuery datatable not refreshing in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable

I am using jQuery [datatables](https://www.datatables.net) in my [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) app. On success of my `GET` API call, I am setting the result to a scope variable and using a `timeout` to initialize the `datatable`.

```
$scope.successCallbackOfAPI = function(data) {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.items = angular.copy(data);
        $("#myDatatable").DataTable();
    }, 200);
};
```

I have a scenario where I have to call the API again and refresh the `datatable` with the new data from the API response. In this case, I will be calling the same `callback` to reinitialize the `datatable`.

The `datatable` still hold the previous data before refreshing even though the `scope` variables are getting updated.

Is there a way to achieve this without using a `directive`?

Comment: Why are you using timeout for?  Is it because $("#myDatatable").DataTable() is asynchronous?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't initalize otherwise

Comment: i can suggest you to try [angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/). this [case](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/dataReloadWithAjax) seems to be good for you

Comment: Need the html to be able to answer

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem I created different function to update my table.
It had this part of code:

```
dataTable.clear().draw() 
dataTable.rows.add( NEWDATA );
dataTable.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Apply this code before the api call or in the render() function.

var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();
 
table.clear().draw();  // To reset the table
```